# The "\" is missing when comments is updated

Tags: comments, buddypress, htmlspecialchars-decode

When I update the comment in the following page, the “\” is missing.

> I find that the problem is due to the plugin **buddypress**.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Ynu.png]

How to avoid the wordpress comment editor converting characters like “\” to html? There is no problem when I post a new comment or edit a post. It happens only when I edit and update the existed comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked with 4.9.1 as well as 5.0-alpha there is no problem with '\'. Please check it after deactivating all plugins and activating the default theme of WordPress.